# How do I reset a self-hosted Wordpress URL?

Tags: database, migration

i was using a wordpress install on an ubuntu server virtual machine.  At first the adapter was host-only at an address of 192.168.55.55.  The host had this on a vboxnet0 subnet.
i changed to bridged adapter to try port forwarding from the router, and now i cant access the page with the new address.
the new address is 192.168.1.5 and everything appears fine on routing tables of host.
i also cleared the dnsCache on the host.
but when i type in:
192.168.1.5/wordpress
in the browser, the activity bar shows it is trying to contact the old ip of 192.168.55.55, which was the vboxnet0 host-only adapter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by using copy&replace in the SQL file. Export the database. Use your favorite text editor and do a copy&replace and import it into a new database.

Then you go to wp-config.php and you change the WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL to the new host. Then you change the databasename. You also need to ensure that the same db user has access to the database.

Btw: There is a separate stackexchange for wordpress. Check out [How do I move a Wordpress site to another server?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5105/how-to-move-a-wordpress-site-to-another-server)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script to do the database find and replace without needing to do the SQL dump. Usual caveats apply - take a backup and delete the script after use. It's actually a better option that the text editor find & replace as it accounts for serialized arrays, which a text editor find & replace doesn't.

[Wordpress (and others) search and replace tool](http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

You'll still need to make the wpconfig.php edits manually.